# Given a base and an exponent parameter, I want to create my own expt function

Tags: list, recursion, racket

I'm trying to create a "slow" exponent function in racket that takes in a base and an exponent, n. I want create this function and multiply the base by itself n times to get my answer. I think creating a list is the best way to get my answer but I'm running into some issues:

```
(define (slow-expt base n)
  (local [(define listn (make-list n base))]
    (cons (* (- base 1) (first listn))
          (slow-expt base (rest listn)))))
```

my error is that * expects the second argument to be a number, but it should be given (first listn). Any words of advice?

Comment: The argument `n` is expected to be some integer, but your recursive call passes a list at its position. Hence, the second time `(make-list n base)` evaluates, it will throw an error since `n` is now a list. Also, every recursive function needs base case(s). The base case(s) will depend on what you are iterating over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists have nothing to do with this problem, simply multiply `base` by itself, `n` times:

```
(define (slow-expt base n)
  (if (= n 0)
      1
      (* base (slow-expt base (- n 1)))))
```